# What is written inside the ring Yui and Rena share?

Tags: regalia

The ring the sisters share is a central motif of the series, and it shows briefly in the closing credits:

[image: Regalia: ring worn by the sisters Yui and Rena]

I cannot get the whole inscription. What is written in the inside, and in what language?

Comment: *"One ring to rule them all, one ring to find them, One ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them."* lol. though seriously it does kinda look like the [inscription for the Ring of Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Ring#Inscription)

Comment: @Memor-X seems like latin. Also given that it is a pair of rings, that Alecto is the vengeance aspect of the goddess, it might be **"two rings to kick'em arses throughly"**

Answer (score 1):

"Per aspera ad astra."

A popular Latin phrase meaning "through hardships to the stars."